# how to find the tabs tag in tabwidget

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I have a tab host with four tabs and  I want to do an operation on changing a tab.
I know that with `mytabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new ...){...}` we can do operations when changing from a tab to another, but I want a way to find the tab's numeric number that I navigated(changed) to it even **out of "changing tab listener" event**

this is my code:

```
tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
                int mediaPlayerIndex = tabHost.getCurrentTab();
                initViews();  
                }
            });
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking but as I understand with the `onTabChanged(String tabId)` method, the `tabId` parameter is, in fact, the 'tag' of the tab which has been selected.

Comment: tnx dear Squonk for responding. I find a simple way with this codes:
'int i = mytabHost.getCurrentTab();' when using in mytabHost.setOnTabChangedListener() event.
is a way to use this method or any method similar to it out of mytabHost.setOnTabChangedListener() event, in my app??

Comment: I still don't understand. Your question asks how to find the tag but now you are saying you want to use `getCurrentTab()` which actually returns the numeric index of the tab and not the actual tag. Which one do you want? Unless you post code and explain more clearly what you are trying to do, it is very difficult to help.

Comment: I edited question. Plz see it again